# Error importing tensorflow (just installed) python 3.7

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, python-3.7, importerror

I have python 3.7 installed on a Windows 10 machine, no custom stuff at all, to install tensorflow I used:

```
pip3 install --user --upgrade tensorflow
```

but when I try importing it using:
`import tensorflow`
in a python script or shell it gives me the following error:

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Am I doing something wrong?

edit: By the way pip version is 20.0.2, I precedently tried with pip 10.x and got the same result.

Comment: Maybe this could help you : https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/22794

Comment: I was thinking of installing it on my machine without virtual enviroments, (mainly because I was following a tutorial that did it like that) do you have any idea of why the command google itself told me to use does not work?

Comment: not at all, I'm afraid. But I detailed some hits in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/35749 or https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/36859 (and the amount of same duplicate issues) there are some recents problems with tensorflow 2.1 for some windows computers.
A fix so far, is to use tensorflow 2.0 on windows :

```
pip install tensorflow==2.0
```

For more details, this is quite detailed : https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/36167#issuecomment-577886156